Mathematical Introduction to Theory of Time Series Analysis
Assume that the reader has strong background in stochastic calculus (including and beyond continuous time stochastic processes like martingales and Markov chains and others, the construction of Levy processes, construction of Ito integrals, weak solutions to stochastic differential equations ...)  and the statistical theory (including but not limited to statistical decision theory, theory of linear models and generalized linear models, theory of hypothesis testing, and proofs decent amount of well-known theorems ...).
What are some references for the mathematical introduction to the theory of time series analysis ?

Hamilton "Time Series Analysis" is encyclopedic. Brockwell and Davis have an older, more mathematical book, "Time Series: Theory and Methods", which is excellent.

there are so many  books because the  time series field falls under statistics, econometrics and electrical engineering. If you just wanted pure theory, I would say Brockwell and Davis. If you want a combination of applied and theory, maybe Hamilton. Others like Hayashi which has a strong econometrics flavor llike Hamilton.  Anderson ( 1950's ) is an older time series classic.  Priestley wrote a 2 volume set on spectral analysis. It's hard to say what the best are ?

As a student, I could have a bet on Hamilton. No matter what others would say, it can be indeed used for advanced undergrad-beginner grad classes for the language, while bit dry compared to any new applied books, is tame and the author diligently explains almost everything (at one point, you might need to have to read about mixingale from any other source as I thought Hamilton was bit of haste here) ...

Contd. It is an econometrics inclined book and unfortunately doesn't cover many things that otherwise a typical ts book would have. But if you want an early access to the mathematical framework, Hamilton is must. Brockwell-Davis is also a very good book with one of the most exceptional explanations of projection theory in the second chapter. Finally, imo, Anderson is not a book for first timer.
